public url access denied in google storage
I have set up google storage to store user profile pictures on my MERN stack app, I'm facing this storage once sending request to the backend to retrieve the url.
   {message: "Uploaded the file successfully: 9.png, but public access is denied!",…}
    url: "https://storage.googleapis.com/devcret_filesnew/9.png"

inside my bucket i granted access as to all users as following:
`allUsers -> Storage Legacy Bucket Owner
allUsers -> Storage Legacy Bucket Reader
allUsers -> Storage Legacy Object Owner
allUsers -> Storage Legacy Object Reader
allUsers -> Storage Object Viewer`

Dashboard.jsx
...
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file.data);
    const response = await authFetch.post(
      "/fileRoutes/image-upload",
      formData,
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
      }
    );
    console.log(response.data.url);
  };
  const handleFileChange = (e) => {
    const img = {
      preview: URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]),
      data: e.target.files[0],
    };
    setFile(img);
  };
return(
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit} method="post" encType="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="file" onChange={handleFileChange}></input>
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
 </form>);


imgUpload.js
I have putted my key json file in the root of the backend
import fs from "fs";
import { Storage } from "@google-cloud/storage";

const gcs = new Storage({
  projectId: "shaped-timing-xxx",
  keyFilename: "shaped-timingxxx.json",
});
const bucketName = "xxx";
export const bucket = gcs.bucket(bucketName);

function getPublicUrl(filename) {
  return "https://storage.googleapis.com/" + bucketName + "/" + filename;
}

let ImgUpload = {};

ImgUpload.uploadToGcs = (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.file) return next();

  // Can optionally add a pathA to the gcsname below by concatenating it before the filename
  const gcsname = req.file.originalname;
  const file = bucket.file(gcsname);

  const stream = file.createWriteStream({
    metadata: {
      contentType: req.file.mimetype,
    },
  });

  stream.on("error", (err) => {
    req.file.cloudStorageError = err;
    next(err);
  });

  stream.on("finish", () => {
    req.file.cloudStorageObject = gcsname;
    req.file.cloudStoragePublicUrl = getPublicUrl(gcsname);
    next();
  });

  stream.end(req.file.buffer);
};

export default ImgUpload;

this is my route:
const multer = Multer({
  storage: Multer.memoryStorage(),
  limits: {
    fileSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024, // no larger than 5mb, you can change as needed.
  },
});
router.post("/image-upload", multer.single("file"), (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (!req.file) {
      return res.status(400).send({ message: "Please upload a file!" });
    }

    const blob = bucket.file(req.file.originalname);
    const blobStream = blob.createWriteStream({
      resumable: false,
    });

    blobStream.on("error", (err) => {
      res.status(500).send({ message: err.message });
    });

    blobStream.on("finish", async (data) => {
      // create a url to access file
      const publicURL = format(
        `https://storage.googleapis.com/${bucket.name}/${blob.name}`
      );

      try {
        await bucket.file(req.file.originalname).makePublic();
      } catch {
        return res.status(500).send({
          message: `Uploaded the file successfully: ${req.file.originalname}, but public access is denied!`,
          url: publicURL,
        });
      }

      res.status(200).send({
        message: "Uploaded the file successfully: " + req.file.originalname,
        url: publicURL,
      });
    });
    blobStream.end(req.file.buffer);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.code == "LIMIT_FILE_SIZE") {
      return res.status(500).send({
        message: "File size cannot be larger than 25MB!",
      });
    }

    res.status(500).send({
      message: `Could not upload the file: ${req.file.originalname}. ${err}`,
    });
  }
});```


It seems that permissions set were correct, however the error message suggests that the file is not publicly accessible.
One possible reason is that the file uploaded has incorrect permissions. You can try to modify the ImgUpload.uploadToGcs function to set access control permissions when creating the write stream. You can try this function to have the uploaded files available for public access:
ImgUpload.uploadToGcs = (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.file) return next();

  const gcsname = req.file.originalname;
  const file = bucket.file(gcsname);

  const stream = file.createWriteStream({
    metadata: {
      contentType: req.file.mimetype,
    },
    predefinedAcl: "publicRead", // set the access control permissions to public read
  });

  // ... rest of the function
};

By trying to set the predefinedAcl property to publicRead, the setting of the access control permission to public read which should ensure that the uploaded file is publicly accessible.
